# If $A$ satisfies $A^2+I=0$,then show that $A$ is similar to \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A\in M_2(\Bbb R)$ and $A$ satisfies $A^2+I=0$ then show that $A$ is similar to \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}

$A$ satisfies $x^2+1=0\implies $eigen values of $A$ are $\pm i$ over $\Bbb C$ and hence Jordan Canonical Form of $A$ is

\begin{bmatrix} i& 0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix}

Also  \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} has Jordan Canonical Form as

\begin{bmatrix} i& 0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix} over $\Bbb C.$

How to show they are similar over $\Bbb R$?

Please help.Is my approachcorrect??

Comment: Your Jordan forms are wrong; they should be $\begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix}$ (or the same with the diagonal elements swapped).

Comment: There seem to be serious misunderstandings about JCF. Those need to be addressed before tackling the actual question. Deleting my post describing an alternative approach (no references of JCF). At least for the time being.

Comment: Did you mean $A^2+I=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the linear transformation $T:x\mapsto Ax$ from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to itself. Let's pick some non-zero vector $u\in\Bbb{R}^2$. Let $v=Au$. Then
$$
Av=A(Au)=A^2u=-u.
$$
Furthermore, $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{R}$. For if we had $v=\lambda u$ for some real number $\lambda$, then $\lambda$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$. But you noticed already that $A$ cannot have real eigenvalues.

So $\{u,v\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. And we have just showed that the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is
$$\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&0\cr}.$$

The matrices of $T$ with respect to different bases are all similar to each other so we are done.